# PostgreSQL 1 to many trigger procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote this query in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pippo() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  CHECK (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM padre WHERE cod_fis NOT IN (SELECT padre FROM paternita)));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It returns:

> Syntax error at or near CHECK.

I wrote this code because I have to realize a 1..n link between two tables.

Comment: What is the desired results of your function?

Comment: @Andreas: Maybe you can start by telling him where his syntax error is.

Comment: Can you post the table structures and some sample records. It's hard to see what you're trying to do...

Comment: @RobertHarvey, his syntax error is at or near CHECK. We already know that.

Comment: What is `CHECK(...)`? AFAIK it is not a function built into postgresql.

Comment: Can you actually use "CHECK" like that? It defines a column constraint. By the sounds of it, you need a foreign key constraint between your tables. If that's the case, you don't need to mess around with triggers, just go to table properties and add the foreign key constraint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use CHECK here. CHECK is for table and column constraints.

Two further notes:

- If this is supposed to be a statement level constraint trigger, I'm guessing you're actually looking for `IF ... THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'message'; END IF;`
  (If not, you may want to expand and clarify what you're trying to do.)
- The function should return NEW, OLD or NULL.